# cmake: pass include directories to external project

Tags: cmake

I'm using **cmake** and [external project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html) module via `ExternalProject_Add`.

I'd like to specify custom header location for external project (just exactly as if I use `include_directories` in that project, but I am not able to modify its `CMakeLists.txt` and don't want to apply patch).

Is there any possibility to pass some include path to my external project?

I tried `CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=<required path>` without success.

Comment: **What kind of headers** are located in the directory you want to add? If they relates to some 3d-party library, then external project, probably, looks for headers with `find_package()`, so you need to set CMake variables, which affects on this function. Or your case is different?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: My case is different. External project just include headers in some custom location. For main project, for example, I can use `include_directories()` to point to this location, but for external project I don't have access to `CMakeLists.txt`, and I'd like to set environment to that project in my top-level cmake. I already found that `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` is definitely not wnat I'm looking for.

Comment: So you need workaround for badly written external project. `For main project, for example, I can use include_directories() to point to this location` - you may *wrap* external project, *as if* it is compiled in subdirectory, and `include_directories()` is issued in the top-level (handy written) `CMakeLists.txt` . Other possibilities would be passing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with additional `-I` option, or even to redefine compiler, which already have this option.

Comment: I need workaround for badly written package managers in badly written OS :) Surprisingly not every project provides `Find<package>.cmake`, `<package>Config.cmake` or even `CMakeLists.txt`, but provides headers and libraries. All I need just specify **locations** where I can have headers. Just like `include_directories` in my own `CMakeLists.txt`. Yes, I already found solution with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but it looks like a trick and is not completely  portable. Wrapping seems even more crappy. But thanks for your comment. I'm just curious about absence of so simple thing in so powerful build sys.

Comment: Found variable `CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE` ([documentation for it](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_PROJECT-NAME_INCLUDE.html)). According to its description, it allows to inject code into external project builds. Looks like it is what you search.

Comment: Thank you for interesting link, but it can be used only to include some *cmake* code into main project. Nothing related to build environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may execute additional CMake script for external project by assigning path to this script to variable `CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE` ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_PROJECT-NAME_INCLUDE.html)).

Let *external project* uses CMake command

```
project(e_cool)
```

and you want to execute

```
include_directories(/path/to/additional/include)
```

at that moment.

For doing that, you need to prepare cmake script with corresponded content:

**fix_e_cool.cmake**:

```
include_directories(/path/to/additional/include)
```

And pass this script via CMAKE_ARGS option of `ExternalProject_Add` in the main project:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
ExternalProject_Add(<name>
    ...
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_PROJECT_e_cool_INCLUDE=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fix_e_cool.cmake
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Using [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/option.html) will allow you to pass data from the the command line, for example:

```
cmake -DHEADER_PATH="/usr/my/path/file.h" ..
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'd like to pass options to external project via `ExternalProject_Add` command, and I'd like to determine **which** variable is responsible for **include paths**. I definitely know that I can pass arguments to current project via command line.